# Transaction does not fail, but fields are written wrongly

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to store an ordered list of image paths in a Firestore document. The images are uploaded to storage with metadata containing the position and a tag linking to a document. The amount of images to expect is known. Uploading of the images is done nearly simultaneously.

Right know, I do this by storing the list of image paths as an array. 
In short: an image is uploaded, using a transaction a document is read, the array is altered and saved again. The transaction never fails, but sometimes an array item disappears again after another image is uploaded.

My two questions are: is an array the best structure in a NoSql database for this problem? Why do array item disappear despite of the transaction?

```
export const addImageToTag = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    try {
        const tag = object.metadata.Tag;
        const position = object.metadata.Position;

        const tagRef = db.collection(COLLECTION_TAGS).doc(tag)
        const tagSnapshot = await db.runTransaction(t => t.get(tagRef));

        const images = tagSnapshot.data().images;
        images[position] = object.name;

        let uploadCount = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < tagSnapshot.data().imageCount; i++) {
            if (images[i].length > 0) {
                uploadCount++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        let state;
        if (tagSnapshot.data().imageCount === uploadCount) {
            state = STATE_ACTIVE;
        } else {
            state = STATE_UPLOADING;
        }

        await tagSnapshot.ref.update({
            images: images,
            state: state
        });

        console.log('Image ', position, ' of tag ', tag, 'added')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Call failed: ', error)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The second question is answered, actually putting the code in the transaction block did the trick. I had read that referencing to the tag document using `tagSnapshot.ref` was sufficient, which was false.

```
export const addImageToTag = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    try {
        const tag = object.metadata.Tag;
        const position = object.metadata.Position;
        const tagRef = db.collection(COLLECTION_TAGS).doc(tag)

        await db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
            const tagSnapshot = await transaction.get(tagRef)

            const images = tagSnapshot.data().images;
            images[position] = object.name;

            let uploadCount = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < tagSnapshot.data().imageCount; i++) {
                if (images[i].length > 0) {
                    uploadCount++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            let state;
            if (tagSnapshot.data().imageCount === uploadCount) {
                state = STATE_ACTIVE;
            } else {
                state = STATE_UPLOADING;
            }

            transaction.update(tagRef, {
                images: images,
                state: state
            });

            if (state === STATE_ACTIVE) {
                console.log('All images of tag ', tag, ' were succesfully added')
            }
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Call failed: ', error)
    }
});
```